# Pagination not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, html

The following code below is an e-commerce website that I'm working on. The pagination selects the correct thing for the first page of the query but selects the wrong thing on the second page. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php ob_start(); 

include "config.php";
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
  $amount = urlencode($amount);
  $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
  $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
  $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 0;
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
  $data = explode('.', $data['3']);
  $data[0] = str_replace(" ", "",preg_replace('/\D/', '',  $data[0]));
  if(isset($data[1])){
    $data[1] = str_replace(" ", "",preg_replace('/\D/', '', $data[1]));
    $var = $data[0].".".$data[1];        
  } else{
    $var = $data[0];
  }
  return round($var,2); }
?>
<?php require_once("../include/membersite_config.php"); ?>
<?php
    // Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("RichWebmasterReg.db.10749243.hostedresource.com","RichWebmasterReg","Apple@1993","RichWebmasterReg");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Products</title>
<link href="../jscss/pproducts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../jscss/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../jscss/heads.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<?php
require('../nmheader.php');
?>
<br><br><br><br>
<?php


///////////////////Pagination/////////////////////////////////////
$perpage = 8;                                                    //
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT count(p_name) from product ");//
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0)/ $perpage );         //
$page = (isset($_GET['page']))? (int)$_GET['page']:1;            //
$start = ($page - 1) * $perpage;                                 //
/////////////////// EndPagination//////////////////////////////////
//$query="SELECT * FROM product ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
session_start();

$category1 = $_REQUEST['categorys'];
switch($category1)
{
case $category1 == 'ALL':
$category = 'ALL';
$query="SELECT * FROM product ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$sel = 1;
break;  

case $category1 == 'BOTTLES':
$category = 'BOTTLES';
$sel = 2;
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat = 'bottles' ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
break;

case $category1 == 'EXERCISE APPAREL':
$category = 'EXERCISE APPAREL';
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat = 'exercise apparel' ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$sel = 4;
break;

case $category1 == 'TOP SELLERS':
$category = 'TOP SELLERS';
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat = 'Top sellers' ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$sel = 6;
break;

case $category1 == 'MUSCLE FORMULAS':
$category = 'MUSCLE FORMULAS';
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat = 'muscle formulas'ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$sel = 5;
break;

case $category1 == 'SPECIALS':
$category = 'SPECIALS';
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat = 'specials' ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$sel = 7;
break;

case $category1 == 'SUPPLIMENTS':
$category = 'SUPPLIMENTS';
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat = 'suppliments' ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
$sel = 3;
break;

default:
$query="SELECT * FROM product ORDER by date_added DESC LIMIT $start, $perpage";
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);
$showing = $perpage > $total? $total: $perpage;
?>

<div style="font-family:Oswald; font-size:120%"><?php echo $category;?> </div>
<form action="products.php" method="post" >
<select name="categorys" style="padding:0px !important; font-size:12px !important; ">
<option value="ALL" <?php if($sel == 1)echo 'selected';?> >All</option>
<option value="BOTTLES" <?php if($sel == 2)echo 'selected';?>> Bottles</option>
<option value="SUPPLIMENTS" <?php if($sel == 3)echo 'selected';?>>Supplements</option>
<option value="EXERCISE APPAREL" <?php if($sel == 4)echo 'selected';?>> Exercise Apparel</option>
<option value="MUSCLE FORMULAS" <?php if($sel == 5)echo 'selected';?>>Muscle Formulas</option>
<option value="TOP SELLERS" <?php if($sel == 6)echo 'selected';?>>Top Sellers</option>
<option value="SPECIALS" <?php if($sel == 7)echo 'selected';?>>Specials</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
<div style="background-color:#CCC; width:1064PX">Showing <?=$showing?> of <?=$total?> Results</div>
<?php



$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
echo "<table width='1064px' cellspacing='10px' >";
echo '<tr width:210px;" height="40%">'; 

  session_start();
for ($i = 1; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $i++) { 
  $name = $row["p_name"];$name = strtoupper($name);
  $number = $row["p_number"];
  $price = $row["p_price"];
  $url = $row["p_url"];
  $manufacturer = $row["p_man"];
  $p_desc_link = $row["p_desc_link"];
  if($_SESSION['mon'] = 'JMD')
  {
    $price = currency(usd,jmd,$price);
  }

  if($_SESSION['mon'] = 'USD')
  {
    $price = $row['p_price'];
  }

 $cur = $_SESSION['mon'];

  $user =  $_SESSION['user'];
    echo "<td>
        <form action='http://definitionxjm.com/product_page.php' method='post'>
         <input type='hidden' name='inum' value='$number'>
         <input type='image' src='http://www.definitionxjm.com/$url' title='More Details' alt='More Details'>
         </form>
        <br>
        <div class='productname' ><a target='_blank' style=' color:#727172; text-decoration:none !important;' href='$p_desc_link'>$name</a></div> 
        <br>
        <div class='productdetails'>
            Manufacturer: $manufacturer<BR>
            Item number : $number<br>
         </div>
        <br>
         <div class='PRODUCTPRICE'>$cur $price</div><br><br>
         <div width='210px'>
         <div style='width:104px;  float:left'>
         <form action='http://definitionxjm.com/shopping/renderCart.php' method='post' >
         <input type='hidden' name='user' value='$user'>
         <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
         <input type='hidden' name='itemNum' value='$number'>
         <input type='image' src='../images/ADD-TO-CART.png' width='87' height='36'>
         </form>
         </div>

         <div style='width:104px;  float:right'>
         <form action='http://definitionxjm.com/product_page.php' method='post'>
         <input type='hidden' name='inum' value='$number'>
         <input type='image' src='../images/DETAILS.png' width='87' height='36'>
         </form>
         </div>
         </div>
    </td> 
    ";                    
    if (($i % 4 == 0) && ($i < $total)) { 
        echo '</tr><tr width:20%;" height="40%">'; 

} 
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';



     if($pages >= 1 && $page <=$pages)
     {
        for($x = 1; $x<= $pages; $x++)
        {
            echo '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
        }
     }

?>



</div>
<?php require('../footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your variable $start will be $start = ($page - 1) * $perpage+1;

Comment: you need to send `categorys ` again with page number in anchor tag .. other wise when you hit for 2nd page it will always come in default condition of switch case

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: in addition to suggestion by @NullPoiиteя I noticed that you are using mix of mysqli_* and mysql_* .. This is bad practise

Comment: why so many session_start() ?

Comment: This is pretty nasty code. You should really explore some PHP frameworks. Look into separation of concerns and the MVC architecture model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the correct offset.

Set `$start` to `$start = ($page - 1) * $perpage+1;`.