# accessing specific number of record from database

Tags: php

1. user enter website
2. He viewed 5 record from database.
3. on clicking next button he can view next 5 record .
4. on clicking prev button he should  be able to view prev 5 record.

Basically, user should be able to access database page by page.

Comment: You've forgotten to add your code to the question.

Comment: You are looking for `pagination`.

Comment: Check the FAQ for [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some tutorials like this:
http://aspektas.com/blog/really-simple-php-pagination/

There are also many questions similar, take a look at this: [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination)

It's not too difficult

Answer (score 0):

you can use PAGINATION functionality.
for that you have to use LIMIT in query.