# Pagination on gallery

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

A little newbie here.
I want to do simple pagination on this. This code show images from curent category. My goal is to show one image at the time and to have just 2 buttons for 'Prev' and 'Next' image. 
Any help is appreciate.

```
            <?php
        $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE img_category = '$cat_id' LIMIT 0, 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($con));

        function getAllRows($dbResult) {
            $rows = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) { $rows[] = $row; }
            return $rows; }

        foreach ($rows = getAllRows($result) as $row) {
            echo "<div id=\"picture\">";
            echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$row['name']."\" /></a><br />";
            echo "<div id=\"caption\">".$row['caption']."</div></div><br />"; }
        if (count($rows) == 0) { echo "There is no images!\n"; }
```

I found some tutorial but something doesn't work as expected. Whenever I click 'Next' button doesn't load next image in this category but stay same image. Any help?

```
            $q="select count(*) \"total\"  from images";
        $ros=mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($ros);
        $total=$row['total'];
        $dis=1;
        $total_page=ceil($total/$dis);
        $page_cur=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
        $k=($page_cur-1)*$dis;

        $q="select * from images limit $k,$dis";
        $ros=mysqli_query($con, $q);

        echo '</table>';
        echo '<br/>';
        if($page_cur>1)
        {
            echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&id='.($page_cur-1).'" style="cursor:pointer;color:green;" ><input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:120px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Previous "></a>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '';
        }

        if($page_cur<$total_page)
        {
            echo '<a href="pic.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'&id='.($page_cur+1).'"><input style="cursor:pointer;background-color:green;border:1px black solid;border-radius:5px;width:90px;height:30px;color:white;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;" type="button" value=" Next "></a>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '';
        }

        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Parametrise your mysqli mate. Vulnerability to injection the way you have it.

Comment: I think that here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination

Comment: Are there lots of images? Are the image files very large?

Comment: for now they are not a lot and max size of image will be ~1.5-2mb.. normaly ~500-700kb

Comment: Try changing `&id='.($page_cur+1)'` to `$page='.($page_cur+1).'`