# Automatic add next page when row count is more than given value

Tags: php

Is there any way to create next page automatically when there are more than 20 rows?

Comment: what do you mean with "next page"? do you have a code sample for us?

Comment: Bro i am Getting data from my mysqldatabase and i want when the data is more then 20 rows it will automatically create next page or view Next link so user can see more data

Comment: if you aren't more precise, we won't be able to help. so, again: what do you mean with "next page"?

Comment: Bro Do u use Gmail ?? when u click on inbox all emails are come from database but when u click on next button then other 20 will show up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a frontend-side pagination only (and do not handle lots of data), have a look at this jQuery plugin:

https://datatables.net/

This is easy to integrate and very useful!

If you are talking about a server-side pagination, see http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html. If you do not like that specific one, there are plenty of these tutorials out there.

The basic knowledge you need for the SQL side of things can be found here: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Comment: Thats why i want but thats too much HARD :(

Comment: how many rows do you have in total?

Comment: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-make-php-pagination_262.html IS this What i want ?

Comment: I dont know i want to get links from mysql database

Comment: ok, how many links do you expect to be in the database?

Comment: you do not understand me. :) the question is how much data you have to handle. if it is a table with links of about <= 200 (would then be 20 pages), it can be handled using the jquery plugin i mentioned without the user getting a significant loading delay.

Comment: i have a data with thousands of Links

Comment: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php I get my work Done Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a sql limit to limit the output for 20 rows, then a link at the bottom of the page to create a new page with a new limit of 21-41 and so on...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 0, 20
```

That will output the first 20 lines, then you'll need to programatically do the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 21, 41
```

You will need to hold the variables in a PHP statement, and when the user presses the next page button, it will $_GET the variable from the header and add 20 to each of the numbers.

Comment: Any Code or website where i can learn this?

Comment: http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html