# how to display limited products per page using php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am creating my first ever project on the topic "online mobile store" on NETBEANS IDE using PHP  and MySQL as backend,
on a page products.php I want to display 1st 10 products, then by clicking on **NEXT** button next 10 products will display....

Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Front-end can never be PHP, Here is an article about pagination system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the LIMIT sentence on  the Mysql query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,10
```

The first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return

You will need to increase by 10 the first number using PHP.

For example, if you want the second page (from 10 to 20) your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10,10
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PHP and MySQL are both backends. HTML/CSS/JS is for frontend.

Second, the thing is achieved by altering your query using LIMIT.

- For first ten : mysql_query(".... LIMIT 0, 10");
- For second ten: mysql_query(".... LIMIT 10, 20");
- ... and so on

Where you get the START and OFFSET from your URL like this:

- example.com/article.php?page=0 -> LIMIT 0, 10
- example.com/article.php?page=1 -> LIMIT 10, 20

I leave the algorithm to you ;)