# php records navigation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, paging

```
<?php 
$host='localhost'; 
$user='root'; 
$password='root'; 
$database='database'; 

$startindex=@$_REQUEST['seek']; 

$db=mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) 
or die ("Impossibile connettersi al server $host"); 

mysql_select_db($database, $db) 
or die ("Impossibile connettersi al database $database");



$query="SELECT * FROM ordini_master"; 
$dbResult=mysql_query($query, $db); 
$AffectedRows=mysql_affected_rows($db); 

mysql_data_seek($dbResult, $startindex); 

$row=mysql_fetch_row($dbResult); 

foreach($row as $k=>$v) 
{ 
    $myfield=mysql_fetch_field($dbResult, $k); 
    print($myfield->name . " : $v <br/>"); 
} 

mysql_free_result($dbResult); 
mysql_close($db); 

print("<br/>Seleziona il record<br/>"); 

for($index=0; $index<$AffectedRows; $index++) 
{ 
    print("<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?seek=$index\" >" . 
    ($index+1) . "</a> "); 
} 
?>
```

This code allow the navigation between a query records, so it create a page foreach record in database and so shows one record time. How can i modify that code to paging every 10 records? So i want to show 10 records time and create a page for the next.

Sorry for my english (I'm italian) , i hope you can help me.

Comment: You should use the COUNT command of SQL and divide the result from the records you need.

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` to get as many records as you wish.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Here is your modified code. This should work for your.
I haven't tested it but give it a try:

```
<?php 
$host='localhost'; 
$user='root'; 
$password='root'; 
$database='database'; 

$startindex=(isset($_REQUEST['seek']) ? $_REQUEST['seek'] : 0); 

$db=mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) 
or die ("Impossibile connettersi al server $host"); 

mysql_select_db($database, $db) 
or die ("Impossibile connettersi al database $database");

$queryCnt = "SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM ordini_master"; 
$CntRow=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query, $db));
$CntData = $CntRow[0];

$step = 10;
$query="SELECT * FROM ordini_master LIMIT $startindex, $step"; 
$result=mysql_query($query, $db); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $k=>$v) { 
        $myfield=mysql_fetch_field($result, $k); 
        print($myfield->name . " : $v <br/>"); 
    } 
} 

mysql_free_result($result); 
mysql_close($db); 

print("<br/>Seleziona il record<br/>"); 

for($index=0; $index<$CntData; $index=$index+$step) { 
    print("<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?seek=$index\" >" . 
    ($index+1) . "</a> "); 
}
```

Use the information from `tadman` too.
It's very important to do something to prevent SQL injection and it's also necessary to use PDO or the mysqli extension because the mysql extension will not longer be supported.

Comment: what is the meaning of the variable '$v' ?

Comment: @LuigiDaddario I have edited my answer. Now `$v` will be used. But I haven't tested the code. Please adjust it as you need it.

Comment: but the problem is that it doesn't show the paging, but i if to change the seek directly from the url (e.g. http://myurl.com/hello?seek=10) it change the records.

Comment: @LuigiDaddario What gives `$CntData` back if you make `echo $CntData`?

Answer (score 0):

What you need first is the `LIMIT` statement from mysql. [MySql states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

As for how to implement it in your code I could not have written a better answer as the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` to display your records and create pages

```
   function getLimitData($start,$limit){
    //getting all items
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=data','root','');
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC limit $start,$limit");
    $results = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;    
}
 //database connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=data','root','');
//pagination pages
  $nav_counter = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
  $page_counter = $nav_counter;
  $nav_counter = rtrim($nav_counter, ".php");
  $cPage = $page_counter + 1;

  //creating next pages
  $first_next = $nav_counter + 1 ;
  $sec_next = $first_next + 1 ;
  $third_next = $sec_next + 1 ;
  $fourth_next = $third_next + 1 ;
  $fifth_next = $fourth_next + 1 ;
  $sixth_next = $fifth_next + 1 ;
  $seventh_next = $sixth_next + 1 ;
  $next_page = $seventh_next + 1;

  //creating previous pages
  $first_prev = $nav_counter - 1 ;
  $sec_prev = $nav_counter - 2 ;
  $third_prev = $nav_counter - 3 ;
  $fourth_prev = $nav_counter - 4 ;
  $fifth_prev = $nav_counter - 5 ;
  $sixth_prev = $nav_counter - 6 ;
  $seventh_prev = $nav_counter - 7 ;

  //row count
  $tableExists = $db->tableExist();
  $ROW_COUNT = $db->getRowCount();

  $numRows= 9; //number of items to be displayed
  //last page
  //last page
  $last_page = ($ROW_COUNT / $numRows) - 1;
    if(!is_int($last_page)){
    $last_page = (int)$last_page + 1;
  }

  $pageNate = '';
    if($ROW_COUNT <= $numRows){
        $pageNate = 'class="hide"';
    }else{
        $pageNate = 'class="exist"';
  }

  //displaying torrents
  $start = 0;
  $limit = $numRows;
  if ($page_counter !== 'index.php') {

   $start = ($limit * $nav_counter);
   }
  //getting number of rows left in the table
  $rows_left = $db->getLimitData($start, $limit);

     $number_rows = 0;
     foreach ($rows_left as $r) {
        $number_rows = $number_rows + 1;
     }
    if ($number_rows < $numRows) {
    $limit = $number_rows;
    }

    $items = $db->getLimitData($start, $limit);
   ?>
```

displaying item

```
         <ol>
        <?php foreach($items as $item) : ?>
          <li><php echo $item['Value']; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
```

pagination code

```
<?php 
  $pages = array();
   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $last_page; $counter++) { 
    $pages[] = $counter;
 }
  //storing pages in array and creating a page if it doesn't exist
    foreach ($pages as $key) {
      $page = $key.'.php';
       //if page doesn't exists create page
        if(file_exists($page)== false && $key <= $last_page){
       copy('index.php', $page);
      }
   }
 ?>




        <p class="pagenav" >
            <a href="index.php" <?php if ($page_counter == 'index.php') {echo 'class="hide"';} ?>>&lt;&lt;</a>
                    <a href="<?php if ($page_counter == '1.php') {echo 'index.php';}else{echo "$first_prev".".php";}  ?>" <?php if ($page_counter == 'index.php') {echo 'class="hide"';} ?>>&lt;</a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$seventh_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($seventh_prev <= 0){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $seventh_prev;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$sixth_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($sixth_prev <= 0){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $sixth_prev;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$fifth_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($fifth_prev <= 0){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $fifth_prev;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$fourth_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($fourth_prev <= 0){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $fourth_prev;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$third_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($third_prev <= 0){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $third_prev;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$sec_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($sec_prev <= 0){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $sec_prev;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$first_prev".".php"; ?>" <?php if($first_prev <= 0 ){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $first_prev;?></a>
                    <a <?php if ($page_counter == 'index.php') {echo 'class="hide"';}else{ echo 'id="here"';} ?>><?php echo $nav_counter; ?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $first_next.'.php'; ?>" <?php if($first_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $first_next;?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo "$sec_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($sec_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $sec_next;?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo "$third_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($third_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $third_next;?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo "$fourth_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($fourth_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $fourth_next;?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo "$fifth_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($fifth_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $fifth_next;?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo "$sixth_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($sixth_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $sixth_next;?></a>
                    <a href="<?php echo "$seventh_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($seventh_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>><?php echo $seventh_next;?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo "$first_next".".php"; ?>" <?php if($first_next <= $last_page){echo 'class="exist"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>>&gt;</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $last_page.'.php'; ?>" <?php if($nav_counter == $last_page){echo 'class="hide"';}else{echo 'class="exist"';} ?>>&gt;&gt;</a>
        </p>
```

[image]