# How to Paginate Data with PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Display five schools per set/pages, use [Bootstrap Pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) to navigate through each set/pages.

**Current Problems:**
I have only been able to find solutions using PHP/SQL Databases (see links below), I want to be able to just use data from an Array to begin Pagination.

[Techumber Simple PHP Pagination](http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html)
[Code Tutsplus Example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)
[Simple PHP Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination)
[PHPFreaks Basic Pagination](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Help and advice is needed,
Thank you in advance!

**Display:**

[image]

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Leaderboard
  */
  get_header();
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <?php
      /* Current User ID */
      $currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
      /* Current User School Name */
      $currentSchoolName = get_the_author_meta('School-Name', $user_ID);
      /* Current User School Region */
      $currentSchoolRegion = get_the_author_meta('School-Region', $user_ID);
      /* Current School Position */
      $currentSchoolPosition = array();
      /* Get Subscribers */
      $subscribers = get_users('role=subscriber');
      /* Subscriber School Array */
      $schoolArray = array();
      /* Foreach Subscribers as Subscriber */
      foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
        /* Subscriber School Name */
        $schoolName = $subscriber->get('School-Name');
        /* Subscriber School Region */
        $schoolRegion = $subscriber->get('School-Region');
        /* If Subscriber School Region matches Current User School Region PUSH School Name to Array */
        if ($schoolRegion === $currentSchoolRegion) {
          array_push($schoolArray, $schoolName);
        }
      }
      /* Reverse School Array Order - High to Low */
      arsort($subscriberValues);
      /* Count Matching Schoole Array Values */
      $subscriberValues = array_count_values($schoolArray);
      /* Foreach Get Current School Position */
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
        $counter = $i++;
        if ($key === $currentSchoolName) {
          array_push($currentSchoolPosition, $counter);
        }
      }
      /* Header Message */
      echo '<p class="text-center">'.$currentSchoolRegion.' Leaderboard</p><p class="text-center">Your school <strong>'.$currentSchoolName.'</strong> is currently in '.ordinal($currentSchoolPosition[0]).' position</p>';

      /* School Leaderboard Table */
      echo '<table class="table">';
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($subscriberValues as $key => $value) {
        $counter = $i++;
          if ($key === $currentSchoolName){
            echo '<tr class="active">';
          } else {
            echo '<tr>';
          }
          /* If 'counter' = '1' display 'Champion School' else display 'counter' value */
          if ($counter === 1) {
            echo '<th scope="row">Champion School</th><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.' Signups</td>';
          } else {
            echo '<th scope="row">'.$counter.'</th><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.' Signups</td>';
          }
          echo '</tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
      ?>
      <nav class="text-center">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li>
            <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <?php

      /* Current School Position - Format */
      function ordinal($number){
        $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
        if ((($number % 100) >= 11) && (($number % 100) <= 13)) {
          return $number.'th';
        } else {
          return $number.$ends[$number % 10];
        }
      }
    ?>
  </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: `array_chunk` might be of interest in your bid to paginate using only an array as data source. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_slice` to reduce your `$subscribers` array to a section of the array, using `$offset` as a starting record number, and `$recordsPerPage` to return a fixed number of results.

```
$offset = $pageNumber * $recordsPerPage;

$subscribers = array_slice($subscribers,$offset,$recordsPerPage);

/* Foreach Subscribers as Subscriber */
foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
....
```