# Column not found in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am to php and I am trying to make a page where you can see the public uploads that are stored in a mysql server.

Out of not where the code I have been using starts giving me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'public' in 'where clause'

I am trying to see how many rows in my db have 'public'

```
// Find out how many items are in the table
$p = 'public';
$total = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uploads WHERE world_access = $p")->fetchColumn();
```

I don't know if it is the php or the sql.

```
// Prepare the paged query
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE world_access = :y ORDER BY upload_time DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
// Bind the query params
$stmt->bindParam(':y', $p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

pagination by [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Comment: `$total = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uploads WHERE world_access = '$p'")->fetchColumn();` - Enclose `$p` with quotes. Also in your PDO, `:y` is string right? then use `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose `$p` with quotes

```
$total = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uploads WHERE world_access = '$p'")->fetchColumn();
```

Also in your PDO, `:y` is string right? then use `PDO::PARAM_STR`