# Building webpages that are indexed for mutiple items and such

Tags: php, web, web-applications, dynamic-programming

I'm moreless curious about webpages that are indexed. An example is gamestop. When you are looking through their product lists they have indexed for multiple tabs like 123456 on the near the bottom of the page. I also notice this with many search engines and pages selling products. I know it sounds dumb to ask a question like this, but I've always been curious how to code a mutiple indexed page like the example listed above. I hope you fellow coders out there could provide some sample code to demonstrate this idea would be perfect. Plus, it could help me in future to see just how it is done. Please provide any info you can. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the INDEXING you are referring is called `Pagination`. Whenever you have multiple items/Records and you want to show only some of them in one page and rest on the other. e.g. you have 100 records in the database and you want to show all of them but loading all at once will slow down your page. So what programmers do is, they use `pagination`.

What they do is , They will show first 10 records on one page. if you have 100 records in database. Then first page will show records from 1 to 10, 2nd page will show 11 to 20 and so on till the end.

use reference
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

or

[Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :) I had a feeling it was something to do with a database driven page but I wasnt sure how it was done :D