# How to make pagination based on primary id

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

I want to do `pagination` based on `primary` `id`  and display 20 `records` per `page`

My `database` having `primary` `id` (auto increment) as **follows**

```
    + users +
       id
    -------
      1
      .
      .
   --------
      145
       .
       .
    upto 5000
```

I'm trying something like this

I'm getting `id` dynamically into this variable  `dynamicIdPassed`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=dynamicIdPassed LIMIT dynamicIdPassed, 20
```

Thank's in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value for stating index dynamically. Suppose in below query I have set 0 starting index for first page. Like for second page it would be 20*2 then for third page 20*3 and so on.

```
SELECT * FROM users limit 20 OFFSET 0;
```