# PHP session not updating variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm building an image slider where images are loaded from my database and displayed inside a php page.

There's a session variable, "number", to remember what is the current database row, in this way I can easily move to next or previous image.

Initially the page was working perfectly, but now when I press on "Next" button to increase session number and move to next page, it remains stuck to "2" and doesn't allow me to read other pages, even if there are multiple ones. I can only browse image no. 1 and image no. 2

I believe the code is correct, but I'm afraid there's something missing about how PHP sessions works, can you confirm it?

//

Comment: Can you confirm what $max=mysqli_num_rows($result); is returning?

Comment: it is used to count the number or rows inside my database (each row contains 1 image) so that it returns the highest value that session number can reach

Comment: @Roy to me that line looks fine, there are 3 opening and 3 closing brachets

Comment: what will be last value of that session?

Comment: Please check your browser url having both **Next** and **Previous** values. If yes it can cause that as a problem for your case.

Comment: I meant that it was returning the right value haha

Comment: @VasimVanzara the last value I can get for session number is 2, as stated. Then it doesn't increase anymore

Comment: @Prodigle now I get you. Yeah it returns the correct value

Comment: I would log if $_Session['Next'] and 'prev' exist on each click. My assumption is at some point they are null when you reach image 2

Comment: echo 'N page '.$page.'<br>'; output of this line is what?

Comment: @Prodigle $_Session['Next'] has never been defined. The only session variable I'm using is $_Session['number']

Comment: sorry, get['nex'].

Comment: @VasimVanzara the output of that line is page number, the $page variable is a way to limit $_session['number'] between 1 and $max (no. of images inside db) http://prntscr.com/kjpbyr

Comment: @Prodigle I'm on image 2 and $_GET['Next'] exists, then I remain stuck to that page but it keeps existing: http://prntscr.com/kjpcxk

Comment: I can only assume it's being reset to one on each click then and then adding one as you've clicked next.

Comment: @Prodigle I agree, that's why I was saying that code looks correct but there's something missing about how sessions work :(

Comment: Can you confirm session variables are being stored between pages at all? Sessions can be disabled so maybe your config is doing that? Your sessions code looks 100% fine to me

Comment: got it haha, check answer

Comment: @Prodigle maybe you're right, in this case I'd have to ask my hosting provider if sessions are disabled in my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_start() must be the second thing on your page after `<?php`. HTML tags must be placed after it or the session will not be started.

Comment: Solved. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use Session to maintain the pagination, instead Keep the pagination status  inside Next, Prev html buttons. I could see some better pagination logic here at:

[Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Comment: Thanks. This fixes my issue.I wanted to learn something more about sessions but I got a solution right here