# PHP MYSQL Pagination With ORDER

Tags: php, mysql

I want some help regarding PHP and MYSQL. What I'm trying is to create pagination system but with ORDER in a field value. Like I'm fetching 700 rows initially, afterward I want next 700 rows with the same order **excluding** the previous rows.

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE '%$user%' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 700";
```

Now, I want the next 700 rows excluding the ones I got in the first request. Same goes if user requests page 3rd and get 700 records excluding first 1400(700*2) records.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Answer (score -1):

Limit can be used with 2 values, the beginning and end of the LIMIT
Your 1st page for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE '%$user%' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 0,700";
```

basically, if page is the variable $p, starting at 1 then:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE '%$user%' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT " . (($p - 1) * 700) . ", " . ($p * 700);
```

Of course, you're 700 jump can also be dynamic, $jump:

```
$jump = 700; // or any other value...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE '%$user%' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT " . (($p - 1) * $jump) . ", " . ($p * $jump);
```