# Form having More than 1900 fields, unable to submit with post method due to querystring limit in php html

Tags: php, html

I have Dynamic table having more than 1900 input box columns, I am unable to submit all fields through form submission, It only passes 60% rows to save page in php. I guess its Querystring Length Limitation.

I have added `.htaccess` file in website folder with following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

php_value post_max_size 512M
```

Even I have added `php.ini` file in `public_html` folder:

```
file_uploads = On

php_value post_max_size = 512M

upload_max_filesize = 512M

max_input_vars 2000
```

I have Godaddy's Shared Hosting Server. I have tried myself best, but form submits only 60% of fields. Even I have changed value of post_max_size value in php Selector option in C Panel.

Comment: Is having 1900 fields usable?  Can it be broken down into logical parts and submitted separately?

Comment: Querystring is not used for form POST requests.

Comment: No Sir, Its Garment's Packing unit, its need bulk quantity to be packed with barcode sticker, dynamic table generates that much barcode at rutime on save page, so need to send that much rows at a time.

Comment: Link to Image of Form:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IHjYrsIHCmrb_iseSWAYkUY8--YAvnFI

Comment: Increase your post max size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GET you certainly run into the [character limit of your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184#417184).

Instead you should use [the POST method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_POST_method) in your form like

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
```

Of course your `max_input_vars` should be more than your fields maximum amount. [This setting limits the superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` separately.

If you are still using POST you should verify that your `max_input_vars` setting is active:

```
<?php
echo "max_input_vars: " . ini_get('max_input_vars') . PHP_EOL;
echo "post_max_size: " . ini_get('post_max_size') . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

You said you added `php.ini` to the `public_html`. Usually the `php.ini` is not located in this folder (maybe a special thing of your hoster?!). And it seems that your php.ini is not well formatted as you use the .htaccess keyword `php_value` and you forget to use an equal sign for `max_input_vars`.

If your php.ini does not work you should try to add all your settings to your .htaccess as follows:

```
php_value post_max_size 512M
php_value max_input_vars 2000
```

As @NigelRen suggested you can split the requests to reduce the total amount of fields as well. This could be solved by using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). It allows sending requests to the server without reloading the page. A good JavaScript framework to realize this could be [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). By that you can update single fields after their focus is lost or you add a separate update button that sends only these rows to the server that have been changed (e.g. every input gets an ID and you count all of them that had focus). Using this method you can also limit the amount of fields that are sent to the server using a simple loop (e.g. only 100 fields are updated per loop).

An alternative method would be a [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script). This means you display only x rows per page, so the user is only able to update those x rows.

I suggest to use AJAX as it will reduce the performance requirements dramatically.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Dear Sir, I have added  php_value max_input_vars 10000 in php.ini file and also in .htaccess file, and finally it worked for me. I am very thankful to your best guidance.

Comment: @Nikhil Please accept my answer if it solved your question ;)

Comment: sorry to ask, i am new to stackoverflow, where i can accept your answer?

Comment: Ok Sir, Thanks for everything. I have Accepted Your Answer.