# How to set Pagination in Codeigniter without Using Library file

Tags: pagination

I am new in codeigniter.Is it possible to set core php pagination concept in codeigniter.I dont want to use codeigniter library files to set paghination.i want to create custom pagination concept using core php concept. Can anyone help me to solved this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705318/simple-php-pagination-script)

Comment: It's a simple php pagination not mvc pattern.