# How can I change a client-side pagination of divs to a server-side pagination?

Tags: javascript, php, html, oracle, pagination

I currently use client-side pagination of divs as the following image:
[image: client-side-pagination]
The divs are loaded by a SQL-Query (oracle). It builds the divs inside a "while" cursor. Each rectangle is one row of my SQL-Query. It loads a lot of rows (more than 4064) and I would like to change it to server-side pagination, where it loads only 20 rows/divs each time that I go to a page or search it in the search bar.

That's the JS code in my PHP file.

```js
       $(function(){
            var keywordInput = document.querySelector("input[name='keyword']");

            function performMark() {
                $(".content.panel").show();

                // Read the keyword
                var keyword = keywordInput.value;
                $('.content').removeClass('hidden');                 
                $('.content:not(:contains(' + keyword + '))').addClass('hidden');

                /* Tentar refazer paginação */          
                var items = $(".content.panel").not(".hidden");

                var numItems = items.length;
                var perPage = 16;

                // Only show the first 2 (or first `per_page`) items initially.
                items.slice(perPage).hide();   

                $("#pagination").pagination({
                    items: numItems,
                    itemsOnPage: perPage,
                    cssStyle: "light-theme",

                    // This is the actual page changing functionality.
                    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                        // We need to show and hide `tr`s appropriately.
                        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                        // We'll first hide everything...
                        items.hide()
                            // ... and then only show the appropriate rows.
                            .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
                    }
                });                
            };

            // Listen to input and option changes            
            keywordInput.addEventListener("input", performMark);                      
        }); 
        $(function() {
            var items = $(".content.panel").not(".hidden");

            var numItems = items.length;
            var perPage = 16;

            // Only show the first 2 (or first `per_page`) items initially.
            items.show();
            items.slice(perPage).hide();

            // Now setup the pagination using the `.pagination-page` div.
            $("#pagination").pagination({
                items: numItems,
                itemsOnPage: perPage,
                cssStyle: "light-theme",

                // This is the actual page changing functionality.
                onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                    // We need to show and hide `tr`s appropriately.
                    var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                    var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                    // We'll first hide everything...
                    items.hide()
                        // ... and then only show the appropriate rows.
                        .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
                }
            });



            // EDIT: Let's cover URL fragments (i.e. #page-3 in the URL).
            // More thoroughly explained (including the regular expression) in: 
            // https://github.com/bilalakil/bin/tree/master/simplepagination/page-fragment/index.html

            // We'll create a function to check the URL fragment
            // and trigger a change of page accordingly.
            function checkFragment() {
                // If there's no hash, treat it like page 1.
                var hash = window.location.hash || "#page-1";

                // We'll use a regular expression to check the hash string.
                hash = hash.match(/^#page-(\d+)$/);

                if(hash) {
                    // The `selectPage` function is described in the documentation.
                    // We've captured the page number in a regex group: `(\d+)`.
                    $("#pagination").pagination("selectPage", parseInt(hash[1]));
                }
            };

            // We'll call this function whenever back/forward is pressed...
            $(window).bind("popstate", checkFragment);

            // ... and we'll also call it when the page has loaded
            // (which is right now).
            checkFragment();
        });
```

The input "keyword" is the search input.

```html
<input name="keyword" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" onload="performMark()">
```

If anyone is interested in the code, here it is: https://gist.github.com/rodrigokiller/2396a0eb7a8787613120d7a3bade9a4c

The pagination plugin that I'm using: http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js

### EDIT

I made a JSFiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigokiller/n85w0rfh/11/

### EDIT 2

I also have build a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d6fcac6204e99e16d5292a14b293f3a

Comment: "I would like to change it to server-side pagination" Okay, if that is what you want to do .... but, what is your question?

Comment: @MT0 how can I change it to server-side pagination? it's pretty obvious I think so.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/1509264

Comment: @MT0 also, my code has some SQL queries on the PHP side, and there is nothing to do with server-side pagination because I don't know how to start it. That was the question. If you answer the question with the code to do it, I will learn nothing. I would like to know how to change it to server-side. I think that I need to change the JS function to call the DBeach time, but the SQL query is inside the PHP file. And the construction of the divs is also inside the PHP file. Those are some questions that I have. I included a jsfiddle in my OP. I am sorry if my question is too vague

Comment: Or duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3705318/1509264

Comment: I will try to add vue.js and transform the SQL queries into JSON, use the SQL queries inside the javascript, and if I struggle, I will come back here. Also, I will check what @MT0 said that is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: I agree it seems (if I understand the question) a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/1509264.  That same kind of query is shown on page 181 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf), but note that newer SQL syntax is shown in the SO post.