# My program has to show a certain amount of records when a button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, api, phpmyadmin

My problem is that it does add the amount properly as it does at the moment 1-50 and then it goes 11-70 when it is supposed to be 51 to 100 and it does not add the math correctly

`front end`

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Credit Sale</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="page" id="page">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option> 
    <option value="50">50</option> 
  </select>
  <br>
  
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="1" >1</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="2" >2</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="3" >3</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="4" >4</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="5" >5</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="6" >6</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="7" >7</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="8" >8</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="9" >9</button>
  <button name="btn" type="submit" class = "go" value="10" >10</button>


  <div id="test">
  </div>
  <div id="test">

  </div>

</body>

<!--CSS-->

<style>
  .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      margin-left: 5rem;
      margin-right: 5rem;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 15%);
      grid-gap: 1.5rem;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      max-width: 70%;
      max-height: 70%;
  }

  .grid-container>div {
      background-color: rgb(208 207 207 / 80%);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
  }

  .grid-container>div img {
      max-width: 30%;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      background-color: gray;
  }
</style>


<script>
  $(".go").click(function () {
    var pageValue = page.value;
    var buttonValue = this.value; 
    console.log(pageValue);
    console.log(buttonValue);
    $('#test').html('');
    $.ajax('api.php', {
      type: 'POST',
      data: { call: 'employeePage', page: pageValue, button: buttonValue},
      
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        $("#test").html(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {

        $("#test").html('Error' + errorMessage);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

back end

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["call"])) {
    if ($_POST["call"] == "employeePage") {
        try {
            //validate button
            if (!isset($_POST["page"]) || empty(trim($_POST["page"])) && $_POST["page"] != 0 && $_POST["button"] != 0) {
                throw new Exception("Please enter a valid page");
            }
            $pageNum = $_POST["page"];
            $buttonNum = $_POST["button"];
            if ($pageNum != 0){
                $pageNum = $pageNum * 1;
            }
            if ($buttonNum != 1){
                $buttonNum = ($buttonNum * 10)-10;
            } else if ($buttonNum == 1){
                $buttonNum = 0;
            }
            $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die("Connect failed: %s\n" . $db->error);
            $result = $db->query("SELECT *FROM employee ORDER BY id asc LIMIT $buttonNum,$pageNum");

            $display = "<div class='grid-container'";
            $display2 = "<div>";
            if (!empty($result)) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $display2 .= "
                        <div class='grid-item'>
                            <img src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png' />
                                <p>" . $row['ID'] . "</p>
                                <p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>
                                <p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>
                                <p>" . $row['Wage'] . "</p>
                                <p>" . $row['Post'] . "</p>
                        </div>";
                }
                $display2 .= "</div>";
                $display .= $display2 ."</div>";
                
            } else {
                throw new Exception("NO Data Found");
            }
            
            echo $display;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Note: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I have tried changing the offset variable but it does not seem to work i have also tried looking up how to solve this error

Comment: This is not a well narrowed question.  Please only show relevant code when presenting your [mcve].

Comment: i was just adding it to make sure the whole program would work

Comment: Study/Adopt: [Simple PHP Pagination script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3705318/2943403)

Comment: your problem is in sql;

`limit n,m`
n signifies row number of query, and m is limit

so you have to say  `give me m records starting from n row`